# jquery toggle text on row click in first td or div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle text in the first `<td>` in a table for every clicked row. What I have found on the internet before is working but a bit weird (because I mixed few examples to get what I want).

Giving example:

```
<body>
  <table class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover'>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Country</th></tr>
    <tr class="table-row"><td>Yes</td><td>Country</td></tr>
    <tr class="table-row"><td>No</td><td>Country</td></tr>
  </table>

  <script>

    $('.table tbody tr').click( function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var xText =  $this.text();
      $this.closest('tr').toggleClass('notUse use')
      $this.text(xText==="Yes"?"No":"Yes");
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

How can I toggle `<td>` text ( 'Yes' or 'No' ) in every single row on click? So far it's toggling well but moreover my function is removing necessary text in the next `<td>` ('Country'). I want to toggle only 'Yes'/'No' without removing text of next `<td>`.

Comment: Does this need to be with JavaScript/jQuery? This could be implemented using css, and a checkbox.

Comment: Actually i'm using bootstrap so i don't want to mix too much and i have allready on row click event with bootstrap but for different use. Besides i don't like much css so i use bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code, It will allow you to toggle "yes / no " when you click on a tr:

```
$('.table tbody tr').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this).find("td:first");
  var xText = $this.text();
  $this.toggleClass('notUse use')
  $this.text(xText === "Yes" ? "No" : "Yes");

});
```

The trick is to use `.find()` right at the start, combined with `"td:first"` this will select the first `td` in the `tr` your `clicked`

**Working demo**

```js
$('.table tbody tr').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this).find("td:first");
  var xText = $this.text();
  $this.toggleClass('notUse use')
  $this.text(xText === "Yes" ? "No" : "Yes");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Country</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Country</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle on the specific column in table, Try the snippet

```js
 $('.table tbody tr td').on('click', function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     if($this.index() == 0)
     {
       var xText =  $this.text();
       $this.closest('tr').toggleClass('notUse use')
       $this.text(xText==="Yes"?"No":"Yes");
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover'>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Country</th></tr>
 <tr class="table-row">
 <td>Yes</td>
 <td>a@a.com</td>
 <td>Country</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="table-row">
 <td>No</td>
 <td>b@b.com</td>
 <td>Country</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```